# You run insertion how long does it take?

Tags: big-o

You run insertion sort on a set of random integers, for some large n. It takes x seconds to run. Next you run it on 3n random numbers. How long does it take.

My answer was between 3x when insertion sort in linear and 9x when it is n^2. I really am not sure how to set this up and establish a relationship between x and n? Also can I state the 
O(n) = x? and O(n^2) = x?

Comment: Insertion sort has a known asymptotic runtime.

Comment: So it is not a range then it must be some linear answer? 3x?

Answer (score 2):

The insertion sort is average/worst case `O(n2)` but that only gives an indication as to how the running time increases. It does *not* dictate that something with thrice the data takes exactly nine times the duration.

The actual *running time* may be specified as something like `n2 + 1000 seconds` (i.e., with a large constant factor) and still be considered `O(n2)`. Obviously doubling `n` in that case won't give you *exactly* thrice the running time.

However, if it's education-type question, then `9x` would probably be the correct answer.

Comment: For `n -> infinity` random numbers, it should approach its asymptotic worst case, so **O(n^2)**. I imagine that's the point of the *'very large n'*, as that also makes it so setup time (the constant offset) becomes completely dominated by `n`. But you're absolutely correct that it depends completely on how sorted the input values already are.

Comment: OK It must be O(n^2) run time because average/worst case is O(n2)

Comment: @aruisdante, you're correct. As `n` becomes large enough, the constant impact is reduced. I find it's always potentially dangerous applying big-O to _runtimes_ instead of complexity since runtimes are a physiclly limited thing - complexity has to do with no-limit mathematics. A bubble sort can easily outperform quicksort for small-enough `n` (introducing the physical limits). :-)

Comment: Indeed I agree. I was once asked a histogramming question where for the example input sizes the simple **O(n)** way of calculating the histogram would have almost certainly been faster than the setup required to do it properly with a hash map/ BST, especially on an embedded processor with limited RAM and balls-slow dynamic memory allocation.